# Should a plumber automatically choose to auger from the toilet?

Tags: toilet, pipe, drain-waste-vent

I hired a plumber to clear a clog...toilet wouldnt flush, was bubbling, and water was backing into the shower and sink.  He pulled the toilet and started the snake.  When he first said he was going to go in thru the toilet it seemed odd because I didnt remember anyone removing the toilet when something similar happened several years ago, but figured he was the expert and wasnt sure I remembered how they did it before.  I figured he was the expert.

He couldnt get the snake back out.  Long story short, it had gone up the vent...he looked in the crawlspace, but said he couldnt open the pipes down there.  He looked in the attic, said it wasnt poking out of the vent.  He was unable to get his camera to go into the pipe.  He finally told me he was trying to find where the snake went, and I told him I thought there was a pipe that went to the mainline in the backyard.  He found it, looked in it, and didnt see the snake.

Without my agreement, his boss told him to cut the snake, even though I asked him to hold off until I could understand the options better.  Now they want me to pay $400 to replace the snake, but since they 1. Chose to access thru the toilet and 2. Sent the snake up the wrong place and 3. Were unable to figure out where the snake was and 4. Cut the snake when I objected, I do not feel I should pay for the snake.  They say I should because I didnt direct them not to use the toilet to access the mainline.

Shouldnt the plumber have known if using the cleanout was a better option?  Was it my fault because I didnt tell him the best way to do his job?  I didnt even think about its existence until he said something about it going up the vent. Also, since the plumber had to keep consulting with someone by phone as all this was happening, I was beginning to worry about their competence and did not want them to come back in the morning and start digging up the backyard.  Another plumber came, and the snake was hanging off my roof.  Cant they just come get the cable (now laying in my yard) and not have to buy a new cable?

Comment: OMG!  This is not your problem. What a corrupt and incompetent plumber / company. No way are you liable for when they screw up and damage their own equipment.  You should tell them you want them to pay for the next plumber that you called to fix their screw-up. Also, tell them you'll post very negative reviews on every social media site you can find about that company unless they pay for the plumber that fixed what they screwed up.

Comment: Get posting, others need to know how bad they are.

Comment: Would also contact your local TV station, most of them have a consumer watch dog section that businesses tend to change their tune when involved

Comment: As they cut the cable it may be difficult or impossible to satisfactually  re-join the cut ends,  but this is not your problem.   a guy who looks in an attic to find a toilet vent opening is not a plumber.  you've been scammed.

Comment: Also call the better business bureau. I pull toilets all the time and have never gone up a vent. I definitely would not be paying for a cut snake! Any fool would know the snake has to come out. This gets into legal witch is iff topic but you also may need a lawyer because the plumber may put a Lein on your home if there was a contract.

Comment: Record and keep a copy of all dealings with this company.  Phone calls, emails and paper mail.

Comment: It sounds like the contractor has not finished the job at the end of the day and damaged (cut-off) their tool thru his own negligence, I feel he shall compensate you for the waste of time and hiring someone else to finish the mess he created.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a legal/contractual issue.

Answer (score 0):

The snake/cable was "used up" in the course of the job they were hired for, which is the basis for asking you (the customer) to pay for it. It is almost certain that the snake cable must be replaced, not repaired, after being cut. Plumbers commonly snake from the toilet because it's the largest and most easily accessible opening. Large cleanouts are not common in single-family homes, and using that would have been far from a guarantee. That was not an error on the plumber's part.

A customer should not be paying for tools intentionally broken. Providing their own tools is part of the definition of a professional contractor – and the snake is a tool, not a consumable material or "supplies". It was also the plumber's choice (with his boss) not to make additional effort to retrieve it when (in hindsight) it could have been detached and pulled through without damage.

There is no clear answer in facts or proper techniques or conventions, which is the home improvement part of the question. If  you are unable to work things out to your satisfaction with the plumber directly, what remains is a legal question.

Comment: It's not a legal question or matter of conventiom who should pay for the snake. It's the plumber. Doing plumbing is why they were called up in the first place. They are supposed to know what they are doing. Stuff like this is one of the reasons why they get insurance. The plumber needs to resolve the situation. Simple as that.

Comment: Obviously the plumber disagrees, which is why this question is off topic as either opinion-based or a legal issue.